# Why does nodejs debugging not working in VS-code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am getting an error while debugging nodejs in vscode: **Can not connect to runtime process, timeout after 10,000 ms - (can not connect to the target)**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiRhn.png)

**launch.json**

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\server\\js.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why am I getting this error? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi geektanvir, nice to see you here. I'd suggest you to provide more information about OS, and insert data *inside* the question (the script, the command you are trying to execute). A linked image is a great addon, but core info are better placed in the body.

Comment: Windows10 operating system. When I press "run debug" I get the error prompt shown in the image link.

Comment: Are you sure the `launch.json` is the one you posted? Usually you just add the `"port": NUMBER` after the program, not in `NODE_OPTONS`

Comment: I have updated the launch.json. There is no "port": NUMBER though. Do I have to add port number?

Comment: Are you sure this path is correct? `"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\server\\js.js"`. I believe the correct one is `"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\js.js"`

Comment: Yes,The path is correct.